# Как показать блок при фокусе на input и скрыть блок при изчезновении фокуса?

Tags: jquery

Есть `input` с классом `.search_input`.
Как показать блок при фокусе на `input`, и скрыть, если фокус не на `input`'e?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно в обработчике [события focus](https://api.jquery.com/focus/), показывать нужный элемент, а в обработчике [события blur](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) - скрывать

Например так:

```js
$('input').focus(function(){$('#block').show();})
          .blur(function(){$('#block').hide();});
```

```css
#block {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="search" />
<div id="block">block</div>
```

Вариант без скриптов с одним css, и простой версткой

```css
#block {
  display: none;
}
.search:focus + #block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="search" />
<div id="block">block</div>
```

Comment: Это же на css можно сделать, почему автор хочет jquery?

Comment: @Doofy, этот вопрос лучше автору адресовать

Comment: @Doofy, добавил пример с css, но при сложной верстке, когда нужно показывать элемент не соседний и не внутренний, вариант с css, либо очень тяжело реализовать, либо пока невозможно

Comment: @Grundy, я так и подумал о невозможности добраться до элемента

Comment: jquery в примере с css убери)

Comment: @Doofy, готово!

Comment: Я поторопился с формулировкой вопроса. Вообще хотел узнать, как делать такую штуку http://exist.ru (при клике на поисковую форму). Там при клике на поисковую подсказку блок не пропадает. Как нужно поправить код?

Comment: @ВикторПавлов, не понял что за поисковая подсказка, и скорее всего нужно задать новый вопрос, в котором указать **всю необходимую** информацию, в любом случае всегда можно добавить какой-нибудь флаг, проверяя который определять надо ли скрывать блок или нет